# Xcode Instruments launches wrong build

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm using Xcode 14.3 on macOS 13.3.1

When I try to launch my project with Instruments for Profiling, it is launching an arbitrary copy of a bundle with the same bundle ID.

As this project has been in active development for sometime, I have the latest production release installed in `/Applications` and a litany of other builds on my machine.

How can I make Instruments use the executable I've selected?

If it matters, I'm also using CMake to configure my project